# Difference between gem install rails and bundle update, to update Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails but I've installed rails before on my workstation. Now I'm looking to update my rails version. My question is:

What is the difference between `gem install rails` and `bundle update` (with the intention to update my rails)?

Comment: Difference between __install__ and __update__?

Answer (score 0):

bundler gem use your gemfile to install your dependancies gems, it will update all your gems present in your Gemfile if you use like this :

```
bundle update
```

You also can update only rails, in your gemfile :

```
gem 'rails', '*version'

bundle install
```

If you want to upgrade existing rails application, look here :

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

otherwise use :

```
gem install rails --version=*version
```